# Highlighting lines with keywords in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, logging, editor, keyword

I would like to highlight permanently (not as a search result) the logger lines in Eclipse to read quickly the real code.

For example, each line beginning with "logger." would have a light grey background.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2):

I think the closest you could get to such a feature would be activating 'Mark Occurrences' by pressing `Shift + Alt + O` or activating it in the settings. Then, you only have to click on `logger.` and Eclipse marks all occurrences of that line in the file.

I can't think of any way to permanently mark any given expression, though, as this solution will only work with types, methods, constants etc.

Comment: Indeed, I would like to highlight (downlight ?) the whole matching lines permanently.